# Is there a web service that lists filtered question list or forwards them to email?

Tags: support, tags, specific-question, feed

Here's my problem: Rather than hanging around on SO all the time, I would like to create filters, e.g. `[c++]`, `"arrays"`, `"opencv"`, so that when someone posts a question with these in the taglist or the body of the question, I get alerted by email. Or I get them as an RSS feed, or some similar. You get the idea.

Is there a service that currently does this? If not, would you be interested in such a thing, since I'll be building one for myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, you can get a feed of questions with certain tags or combinations of tags, but not the results of a search involving text input.

I'm a bit uncertain if the latter is what you meant, but regardless, the two strings you mention are tags, so here you go:

[Feed of all questions with `[c++]` or `[arrays]` or `[opencv]`](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c%2b%2b+or+opencv+or+arrays&sort=newest)

When you're on a /tagged page, there is a link to the feed at the very bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the filtered RSS feed functionality for SO.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but...

[StackMail - Making the StackExchange Sites Accessible Via Email](https://stackapps.com/questions/895/Stack-Mail)

I could easily extend it to show questions that match a tag.